# By passing string from query parameter in moment() shows moment.invalid

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am making GET api under which I want date time in query parameter. If I simply make log with req.query() it is showing correct string. But if I pass that string in moment() then I am getting moment.invalid('date').

Here is my code:

```
console.log('current time ', req.query.currentTime, moment(req.query.currentTime));
```

and in console, I am getting,

```
 moment.invalid(/* DATE */)
```

Comment: In which format you are getting date? Can you an example of the date you are getting?

Comment: @NirajPatel,I am getting in this formt -> 2020-04-24T11:02:58 05:30

Comment: Do you want to convert it into specific format?

Comment: @NirajPatel, No I want to compare this date time with another date time format. With moment.isAfter() but it is not let that happen..

Comment: To compare date, i suggest both date should be in same format

Comment: Okay,, if I try to log this moment(req.query.currentTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD') it is showing invalid date.. What's wrong in it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212398/discussion-between-niraj-patel-and-jayna-tanawala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your date string contains timezone. You can convert it using following way:

```
moment().parseZone(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```